# Where is the @Autowired annotation supposed to go - on the property or the method?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

Which is more correct?

This (with the @Autowired annotation on the method)?

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyDao myDao)
    {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }
```

This (with the @Autowired annotation on the property)?

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    public MyController(MyDao myDao)
    {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }
```

Where is the @Autowired annotation supposed to go?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to [the Javadoc for Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html), the annotation can be used on "a constructor, field, setter method or config method". See [the full documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) for more details.

I personally prefer your first option (constructor injection), because the `myDao` field can be marked as final:

```
@Controller
public class MyControllear {
    private final MyDao myDao;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyDao myDao) {
      this.myDao = myDao;
    }
```

Constructor injection also allows you to test the class in a unit test without code that depends on Spring.

The second option would be better written as:

```
@Controller
public class MyControllear {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    MyController() {
    }
```

With field injection, Spring will create the object, then update the fields marked for injection.

One option you didn't mention was putting `@Autowired` on a setter method (setter injection):

```
@Controller
public class MyControllear {
    private MyDao myDao;

    MyController() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMyDao(MyDao myDao) {
      this.myDao = myDao;
    }
```

You do not have to choose one or another. You can use field injection for some dependencies and constructor injection for others for the same object.

Comment: According to an experiment I just made (with Spring 3.0) the field can be marked as "final" also in the second option, i.e. it seems to work fine to put @Autowired on a final field and the wiring will actually work at runtime! I suppose it works because Spring bypasses the "final" modifier when it sets the field via reflection. Can anyone confirm/shine some more light into this?

Comment: @Mikko I'm surprised that works. The "final" modifier provides some guarantees for concurrency. If Spring is modifying final fields after construction, you are losing some of those benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation goes with the property, because that's what's being autowired; the property to be automatically set.  [This tutorial](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/52385) has a nice example.  [This more advanced example](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3756831/Java-Tip-Simplify-Spring-Apps-with-Autowired.htm) shows how to use qualifiers to disambiguate the wiring.