# Spring MVC cannot autowire

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I keep getting the below error when my bean is being created, however I am unsure why it is not seeing the bean when I have it declared.  Is there something wrong with the file structure or is there a deeper issue?  I know this will be TLDR for a lot of people but I wanted to include the full flow.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsController' defined in file [C:\Users\ChappleZ\Desktop\CRCart001\CRCartSpring001\out\artifacts\CRCartSpring001_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\cr\controllers\ProductsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [cr.managers.ProductsManager]: : No matching bean of type [cr.managers.ProductsManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [cr.managers.ProductsManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Below is folder structure and related files.

```
 
src
-   Java
     |_ Cr
          |_    Controllers
               |_   ProductsController
          |_    Dao
               |_   Impl
                    |_  ProductsDaoImpl
          |_    ProductsDao
          |_    Entity
               |_   Products
          |_    Managers
               |_   ProductsManager
               |_   Impl
                    |_  ProductsManagerImpl
-   Resources
     |_ Beans
          |_    Daos.xml
          |_    Services.xml
     |_ Config
          |_    BeanLocations.xml
     |_ Database
          |_    DataSource.xml
          |_    Hibernate.xml
     |_ Properties
          |_    Database.properties

Web
-   Resources
     |_ Components
     |_ Css
     |_ Data
     |_ Img
     |_ Js
     |_ Views
-   WEB-INF
     |_ applicationContext.xml
     |_ dispatcher-servlet.xml
     |_ logging.properties
     |_ web.xml
-   index.jsp
```

Products Controller

```
package cr.controllers;

import cr.Entity.Products;
import cr.managers.ProductsManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Products")
public class ProductsController {
    private ProductsManager productsManager;

    @Autowired
    public ProductsController(ProductsManager productsManager) {
        this.productsManager = productsManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/products/{productId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Products findByProductId(@PathVariable long productId) {
        Products products = productsManager.findByProductId(productId);
        return products;
    }
}
```

ProductsDaoImpl

```
package cr.dao.impl;

import cr.Entity.Products;
import cr.dao.ProductsDao;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductsDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ProductsDao {
    @Override
    public void save(Products products) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(products);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Products products) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(products);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Products products) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(products);
    }

    @Override
    public Products findByProductId(Long productId) {
        List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Products where productId=?",productId);
        return (Products)list.get(0);
    }
}
```

ProductsDao

```
package cr.dao;

import cr.Entity.Products;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public interface ProductsDao {
    void save(Products products);

    void update(Products products);

    void delete(Products products);

    Products findByProductId(Long productId);
}
```

ProductsEntity

```
package cr.Entity;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name= "Products")
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name= "productsId")
    private int productsId;

    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    @NotNull
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "ProductDescription")
    @NotNull
    private String productDescription;

    @Column(name = "MfgCost")
    private double mfgCost;

    @Column(name = "Price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "SalePrice")
    private double salePrice;

    @Column(name = "CreationDate")
    private Timestamp creationDate;

    @Column(name = "DeletedIndicator")
    private Boolean deletedIndicator;

    @Column(name = "ImagePath")
    @NotNull
    private String imagePath;

+Setters and Getters + ToString (Not added to keep post shorter)
```

ProductsManager

```
package cr.managers;

import cr.Entity.Products;

public interface ProductsManager {
    void save(Products products);

    void update(Products products);

    void delete(Products products);

    Products findByProductId(Long productId);
}
```

ProductsManagerImpl

```
package cr.managers.impl;

import cr.Entity.Products;
import cr.dao.ProductsDao;
import cr.managers.ProductsManager;

public class ProductsManagerImpl implements ProductsManager{
    ProductsDao productsDao;

    public void setProductsDao(ProductsDao productsDao){
        this.productsDao=productsDao;
    }

    public void save(Products products) {
        productsDao.save(products);
    }

    public void update(Products products) {
        productsDao.update(products);
    }

    public void delete(Products products) {
        productsDao.delete(products);
    }

    public Products findByProductId(Long productId) {
        return productsDao.findByProductId(productId);
    }
}
```

Daos.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Products Data Access Object -->
    <bean id="productsDao" class="cr.dao.impl.ProductsDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

services.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Products object -->
    <bean id="productsManager" class="cr.managers.impl.ProductsManagerImpl">
        <property name="productsDao" ref="productsDao"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

BeanLocations.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>


    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="../beans/daos.xml"/>
    <import resource="../beans/services.xml"/>
</beans>
```

DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hibernate.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Database.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=root
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!--================================= Component Scan ======================================-->
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Controller to configure as beans -->
    <!-- This entry looks for annotated classes and provides those beans in the Spring container.   -->
    <!-- So there is no need to declare bean definitions in the XML configuration -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="cr"/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!--SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is already configured, disabling the default HandlerMappings.
     The DispatcherServlet enables the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, which looks for @RequestMapping annotations on @Controllers. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <!-- Based on the value of the order property Spring sorts all handler mappings available in the context and applies the first matching handler. -->
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

logging.properties

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you get your error:

```
private ProductsManager productsManager;

@Autowired
public ProductsController(ProductsManager productsManager) {
    this.productsManager = productsManager;
}
```

This is not the proper way to autowire a bean.

Replace all of that with

```
@Autowired
private ProductsManager productsManager;
```

You don't have to create a constructor for that. Alternatively, you can autowire a bean on a setter:

```
private ProductsManager productsManager;

@Autowired
public setProductsManager(ProductsManager productsManager) {
    this.productsManager = productsManager;
}
```

Comment: This actually got me the closest to where I needed to be, Thank you Raul.

Comment: actually you can use `@Autowired` on setters/constructors, as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746574/where-is-the-autowired-annotation-supposed-to-go-on-the-property-or-the-metho

Comment: -1: `@Autowired` on a constructor is perfectly valid.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation

Answer (score 2):

1. Your applicationContext.xml does not import any of the XML files with the beans definitions, so these dont get processed
2. Your MVC dispatcher servlet scans 'cr' package for Spring-annotated classes. Your ProductsManager class is not annotated so is not found by component scanning, but ProductsController class is found, and cannot be instantiated since Spring does not have knowledge of your ProductsManager class.

Recommendations:

Import bean definitions XML in main application context. Do not instantiate ProductsController in root context - all @Controller beans should belong to MVC servlet context. You can achieve this with the following tags in MVC xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="cr" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

and in main context either add @Component annotations to your classes and use this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="cr" use-default-filters="true">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

or skip component scanning completely and manually define your beans in XML

Comment: I added the first block to my dispatcher-servlet.xml and added a import to my application context. This allowed me to see another error complaining about a mysql noclassfound.  I will keep going and see if I can get past the next couple errors. But so far this looks like the right answer :)

Comment: I tried both of those blocks for the dispatcher-servlet and I am getting 404's when I try to access the controller. However nothing is showing up on my tomcat log.

Comment: You shouldnt use both blocks in servlet context. First one is for servlet context, second for root context

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:-

Load services.xml in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 //Load Services.xml here like <param-value>actualPath/services.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

import dao.xml in service.xml

```
//Like <import resource="classpath:actualClassPath/dao.xml" />
```

Then

You can autowire productsManager directly in the controller.
You can autowire productsDao directly in the productsManager.

Since you autowire productsManager,there is no need of constructor in the controller.
Since you autowire productsDao ,there is no need of constructor in the productsManager.

Below bean config is enough.

```
<bean id="productsManager" class="cr.managers.impl.ProductsManagerImpl"/>
```

Below code is enough for controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Products")
public class ProductsController {
 @Autowired    
 private ProductsManager productsManager;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/products/{productId}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)

 @ResponseBody
 public Products findByProductId(@PathVariable long productId) {
    Products products = productsManager.findByProductId(productId);
    return products;
  }
 }
```

Option2 :- (I wouldn't recommend this ( this is for better understanding))

Define productsManager,productsDao bean in applicationContext.xml

then

modify controller like above code it will work.