# AutoWired Setters rather than AutoWired instance variables in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I am a junior engineer on a Java team that uses Spring. We have been coached to Autowired Setters of instance variables rather than Autowiring the actual instance variable. I am slightly confused as to why we do this, what are the advantages of doing this and possible shortfalls of handling dependency management in this way ?

Comment: You can find answer for your question here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746574/where-is-the-autowired-annotation-supposed-to-go-on-the-property-or-the-metho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations from me (actually 3 years in Java EE):

Advantages:

- you can add some extra validation or logic in setters methods
- you can avoid to use reflection in junit testing for some special cases
- setters can be overridden so you can inject something else

Disadvantages:

- in most cases this validation is not necessary because you are injecting another services
- you have to have a lot of useless setters and getters in your code. For example in my code I am using normally about 5 DAO classes per service so this is 10 extra methods to write which gives me about 60 extra lines.
- mostly you do not need to inject another DAO or Service after the application is initialized.
- setters/ getters can not be used later because in spring you are working on interfaces rather than concrete implementations. It is a bad practice to have setters and getters on interfaces.

Personally I prefer instance variable or constructor injections. But this is service dependent. I would not say that using setters is better. It has just different purposes.