# Spring @Autowire on method

Tags: spring, autowired

I've seen in many example the use of @Autowire in spring on a method.
For example in configuration file:

```
@Component
public class SomeConfigFile{

@Autowire
public void someMethod(SomeBeanInstance someBean){
//bla bla
}
```

I guess someBean in my example above injected to the method by Spring but when does this method is called? and how calls it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642494/1439560, does it answer you?

Comment: Thank you. Just what I've been looking for :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method, or config method as to be
> autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities. This is an
> alternative to the JSR-330 Inject annotation, adding
> required-vs-optional semantics.

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html