# FindBugs null issue with Spring @Autowired in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin

I am using the [findbugs](/questions/tagged/findbugs) [Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/findbugs-eclipse-plugin) (3.0.1.20150306-5afe4d1), [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) (4.2.2.RELEASE), and [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) (Mars.1 (4.5.1)) together and I am receiving the following FindBugs bug in Eclipse.

> Non-null field `env` is not initialized by `new
>   org.test.app.config.AppConfiguration()` [Scary(8), Normal confidence]

I am using using the default constructor and using autowiring to initialize the `env` variable.  I also have a [`PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation which gets called after everything is wired and accesses the `env` variable to make sure it was initialized correctly.

How can I make this error disappear without turning off the FindBugs plugin and still using the [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation?

```
package org.test.app.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.test.app" })
@PropertySource("classpath:/${spring.profiles.active:local}.properties")
public class AppConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Dump profile info.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void details() {
        log.debug("** App application context, active profile(s)={}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    }
}
```

**Update**

I tried using a constructor per @spoonybard896 suggestion, but it did not work.  I received the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.test.app.config. AppConfiguration $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbece1d7.<init>()
[STDOUT] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
[STDOUT] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
[STDOUT] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiat‌​e(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a non-default constructor instead?

```
private final Environment env;

@Autowired
public AppConfiguration(final Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}
```

**EDIT**

The above approach would work for a `@Controller` instance, but will not work for `@Configuration`. After doing some quick [research](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) it turns out that:

> `@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component`, therefore `@Configuration` classes are candidates for component scanning (typically using Spring XML's `<context:component-scan/>` element) and therefore may also take advantage of `@Autowired`/`@Inject` at the field and method level (but not at the constructor level).

I'm thinking that unless there is some kind of addon for FindBugs that understands Spring annotations (I do not know of one) then you may just need to apply a filter to the FindBugs plugin and have it ignore that particular error in that particular file(or in any Configuration class in general). In Eclipse check out Preferences -> Java -> Findbugs -> Filter Files, and check out [this](https://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/06/false-positives-with-findbugs-on-ioc.html) link which describes a similar problem and resolution, but just make sure to filter out [only the error you want](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR). The goal would not be turn FindBugs off, but instead have it just ignore this one case.

**EDIT 2**

Adding an [annotation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/index.html?edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html) to the class will suppress the FindBugs error for this file only.

```java
@SuppressFBWarnings(
    value="NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR",
    justification="Overriding the check on the env variable because Spring will automatically initialize the variable after the constructor is called and before any public methods are called.")
```

Comment: This works and does have the added benefit of making the `env` variable immutable.  Unfortunately I was hoping to avoid having to clutter my class with this boilerplate code.

Comment: I hear you. Personally, I've always sided with using the constructor approach for testing +mocking purposes later on, but I've also seen fairly large constructors as a result. This question and answer here have some good points about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746574/where-is-the-autowired-annotation-supposed-to-go-on-the-property-or-the-metho

Comment: When I tried this with a more complicated setup it failed to work because [tag:Spring] is looking for the default constructor.  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.test.app.config. AppConfiguration $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbece1d7.<init>()
[STDOUT]  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
[STDOUT]  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
[STDOUT]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80) ~[na:na]`

Comment: Added an edit. I think your best bet is to disable the NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR bug pattern for this class.

Comment: Based on your comment I added the following annotation to my class.  `@SuppressFBWarnings(
        value="NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR",
        justification="Overriding the check on the env variable because Spring will automatically initialize the variable after the constructor is called and before any public methods are called.")`

Comment: Very cool, I was not aware of the SuppressFBWarnings annotation. Much nicer than xml config.