# best approach for velocity email component inside spring container

Tags: spring, velocity

what is the best approach for using velocity component inside spring container.

In my velocity util(emailer) class , i have declared the method for sending email as STATIC to avoid creation of emailer object everytime. Also i have declared the setter injections as static.

Is this the correct way ?

Java:

```
     Class emailer{


    public static Boolean sendEmail(){
     SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();  
     String val = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, template, model);
    msg.setText(val);
    mailSender.send(msg);


    }



    private static MailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
public static void setMailSender(MailSender mailsender) {
    LOGGER.debug("MailSender set successfully");
    mailSender = mailsender;
}

private static VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

@Autowired
public static void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityengine) {
    LOGGER.debug("Velocity Engine set successfully");
    velocityEngine = velocityengine;
}
    }
```

xml changes:
        localhost

```
<bean id="emailHelper" class="emailer">
  <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
  <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"/>
```

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
 <property name="velocityProperties">
 <props>
  <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
  <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
            org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
  </prop>


  </props>
   </property>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use static methods here. Spring can't autowire static methods (see [Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/autowired-static-field-spring-2-5))

But even if you could autowire static methods, it wouldn't be any better than using instance methods. That's because Spring creates beans as *singletons* by default, which means it creates only one instance and it uses the same one for each `@Autowired` property. So it would *not* create a new instance of your emailer object or your mailsender object every time, it would keep using the same one.

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) explains it in more detail.

You should only use instance properties and variables to make it work — in other words, just  remove the word `static` from each one.

Comment: Yes i agree, but VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString method is a static one . How will i use it then in my sendEmail() method ?

Comment: You can always call a static method from an instance method — there's nothing wrong with that!