# @Autowired fails in spring boot web project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a simple Spring Boot web project, right from a template:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldRestApplication.class, args);

    Performer p = new Performer();
    p.perform();
    }
}
```

I have a test to ensure autowiring works, and in fact it does in this test class (examples come from Spring in Action, 4th):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

@Autowired
private CDPlayer cdp;

@Test
public void cdShouldNotBeNull(){
    assertNotNull(cdp);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Performer {

@Autowired
private CDPlayer cdp;

public void perform(){
    System.out.println(cdp);
    cdp.play();
}

public CDPlayer getCdp() {
    return cdp;
}

public void setCdp(CDPlayer cdp) {
    this.cdp = cdp;
}
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class CDPlayer{

public void play(){
     System.out.println("play");
  }
}
```

config:

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan
 public class CDPlayerConfig {

 }
```

However, it doesnt work in HelloWorldRestApplication, I get null.

Adding @ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class) doesn't help.

What do I miss?

Comment: static fields cannot be autowired check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938529/why-cant-we-autowire-static-fields-in-spring for explanation

Comment: I created a POJO in main method and then tried to autowire it's field and it still fails. So removing static doesn't solve the problem

Comment: update the post with your latest code

Comment: When you are creating your own instance how do you think spring is going to autowire things? It doesn't know about it hence no auto wiring...

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't know? Isn't Autowired and Component annotations enough information to perform auto wiring? Dou you also mean i cant inject a wired bean into POJO?

Comment: No you are creating an instance yourself... You should use a spring managed instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling `@ComponentScan` your packages in your main class and get `Performer` class instance from `ApplicationContext` as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@ComponentScan({“package.name.1”,”package.name.2”})
public class HelloWorldRestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldRestApplication.class, args);

    Performer p = ctx.getBean(Performer.class);//get the bean by type                      
    p.perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still fails, I have the same situation with out of the box Spring Starter Project as well

Comment: It's failing because of `new Performer()`, can you try with updated answer?

Comment: It works when I add @Component to Performer but this is OK as well, thanks:)