# Why autowired component with static modified is null?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-integration, autowired

I am trying to inject a component with static modifier as my method which needs it is already static.. but injected component is null when the access modifier static..

@Autowired
Service service; - Works fine

@Autowired
static Service service; - returning null...NullPointerException

Comment: Because http://stackoverflow.com/a/21875258/1240557

Comment: Why do you want it to be static ?

Comment: @Reos - This component need to be used as part of my utility method which is already static.