# Spring Mongo DB with Annotation based configurations

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot and I am trying to make a very simple app that fetches data from Mongo DB by using Dynamic Queries. I am using Intellij as my IDE.

FILE: **application.properties** (inside resource folder)

```
spring.mongo.host=127.0.0.1
spring.mongo.port=27017
spring.mongo.databaseName=spring
```

FILE: **person.java**

```
@Document (collection = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    String id;
    int age;
    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

FILE: **MyRepo.java**

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, String> {
    public List<Person> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

FILE: **Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"mongo.customQueries"})
public class Config {

}
```

FILE: **Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    public static MyRepo myRepo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        MyRepo myRepo = context.getBean(MyRepo.class);
        System.out.println(myRepo.findAllByName("Avishek"));

    }
}
```

When I run the project, I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [mongo.customQueries.MyRepo] is defined
```

What is it that I am missing here? Why is my MyRepo bean not created as most of the examples in net are doing so.

Comment: Remove @Autowired annotation. Not needed when you use context to instantiate MyRepo bean.

Comment: I removed, still not working.

Comment: You can't autowire static fields.

Comment: what is package name for MyRepo class ? it should match the value defined base package in mongo configuration

Comment: Its "mongo.customQueries".

Comment: If someone could just give me a simple example to run Dynamic Queries in Spring boot with mongo. Some examples similar to that of above. Or how can I make the above example correct.

Comment: You can not [autowire static fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938583/3014866) in `Spring`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want to annotation the `MyRepo` in the Main class, please remove it as below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        MyRepo myRepo = context.getBean(MyRepo.class);
        System.out.println(myRepo.findAllByName("Avishek"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If someone could just give me a simple example to run Dynamic Queries
>   in Spring boot with mongo. Some examples similar to that of above. Or
>   how can I make the above example correct.

You can see working example [here](https://github.com/Sergei-Rudenkov/spring_training/tree/master/spring_data%2BMongoDB). And find explanations [here](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/).