# Multiple datasources when using JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am trying to use multiple datasources / database connections in a single spring boot application. The tutorials I find deal with JPA but I wish to use my databases through JdbcTemplate.

Do I need to manually connect like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336965/2480560

Or is there a way to do this mostly with my application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a mixed approach injecting the properties into the data source configuration using @Value annotations

See [Reading values from application.properties Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428826/reading-values-from-application-properties-spring-boot)