# SpringBootApplication does not Autowire my Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having troubles with my Spring Boot initialization. I have this structure in a simple Spring Boot project.

```
com.project.name
|----App.java (Annoted with @SpringBootApplication and Autowire MyCustomService)
|----com.project.name.service
     |----MyCustomService.java (Annoted with @Service)
```

I tried setting `scanBasePackages` property in the SpringBootApplication Annotation but does not work. Anyway I have an `@Bean` annotated and I see that Spring Boot inject it correctly in the app because I can see the log when I run the application like this:

```
2019-03-09 15:23:47.917  INFO 21764 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'jobLauncherTaskExecutor'
...
2019-03-09 15:23:51.775  INFO 21764 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'jobLauncherTaskExecutor'
```

A basic scheme of my AppClass.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }
        //,scanBasePackages  = {"com.project.name.service"}
)

public class App{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    @Autowired
    private static MyCustomService myCustomService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        ...

        myCustomService.anyMethod();//NullPointerException
    }
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
    return executor;
}
```

I guess that I am missing something but I am reading some guides and does not find anything about this.

Comment: Spring never autowires *static* fields. It creates Bean instances, and injects other beans instances into these beans. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner for how to execute code at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring cannot `@Autowire` static fields, use `ApplicationContext` to get the bean

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }
    //,scanBasePackages  = {"com.project.name.service"}
)

public class App{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        MyCustomService myCustomService = (MyCustomService)context.getBean("myCustomService");
        ...

        myCustomService.anyMethod();
    }
}
```

Or you can use `CommandLineRunner`

```
 @SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }
    //,scanBasePackages  = {"com.project.name.service"}
)

public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomService myCustomService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    public void run(String... args){
        myCustomService.anyMethod();
    }     
}
```

Comment: I did a bad refactoring and I broke my application :) Thanks, I think I would have been stuck for a long time with this if it were not for your help. Thanks! Great CommandLineRunner Tip

Answer (score 1):

the problem has been solved before , please see link below

[why can't we autowire static fields in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938529/why-cant-we-autowire-static-fields-in-spring/21875258)