# Cannot invoke "UserRepository.findAll()" because "userRepository" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a login method for my spring application. But when I try to call the
`getUserByAuthentication`
method, I get a null pointer exception. Here is my code:
Function calling the error:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/online")
public ResponseEntity<?> onlineRequest(@RequestBody OnlineRequest onlineRequest) {
    User user = null;
UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
    user = userManager.getUserByAuthentication(onlineRequest.getUsername(), onlineRequest.getPassword());
    if (user!=null){
        user.setLatestTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return new ResponseEntity<>("You are now online, Enjoy!", HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid login", HttpStatus.valueOf(403));
    }
}
```

Get User by Authentication class:

```
public class UserManager {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public User getUserByID(int id){
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    public User getUserByAuthentication(String name, String password){
        Iterable<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.forEach(users::add);
        User user = null;
        for (User u : users){
            if (u.getUsername().equals(name) && u.getPassword().equals(password)){
                user = u;
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    //Initialize
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean hasAccess;
    ArrayList<Integer> inChannels;
    long latestTimeStamp;

    public long getLatestTimeStamp() {
        return latestTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setLatestTimeStamp(long latestTimeStamp) {
        this.latestTimeStamp = latestTimeStamp;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getInChannels() {
        return inChannels;
    }

    public void setInChannels(ArrayList<Integer> inChannels) {
        this.inChannels = inChannels;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public boolean hasAccess() {
        return hasAccess;
    }

    public void setAccess(boolean hasAccess) {
        this.hasAccess = hasAccess;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938529/why-cant-we-autowire-static-fields-in-spring/10944781)

Comment: Yea, the static was just to test if it helped thanks

Comment: if you create the user manager yourself using `new UserManager();`, the `@Autowired` inside of it will have no effect. Let spring inject the instance for you instead.

Comment: One hint that is not directly your question. But never store passwords of users in clear text. Please use the Spring PasswordEncoder and save and compare the encoded password strings.

Comment: I know I shouldn't store passwords like that. I will add an encryption at a later point once the code itself works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@Autowired` without one of the annotation that define a component in spring, so in your case, you can use `@Service` on `UserManager` like this:

```
@Service
public class UserManager {
```

and also don't use `static` on your method, you have to inject the `UserManager` component in the controller, as you do with your repository:

```
@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
```

Then you can use:

```
user = userManager.getUserByAuthentication(onlineRequest.getUsername(), onlineRequest.getPassword());
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yea, I saw that I removed the static, and I will try the service

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the find function into the repository interface.