# How to @autowire some bean into JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using lazy loading with hibernate in my web app.

I would like to load some objects from the database at the parsing stage of the server response

> ```
> @Component
> public class DesignSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Design> {
> @Autowired
> IDesignService designService; <-- is null
> ```
>
> }

Which is totally understandable because `DesignSerializer` is being instantiated with the "new" operator for each object.

I am sure there is a way to inject my bean into that serializer when ever it is created, I just don't know how.

Can you guys help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: If DesignSerializer is mark with @Component, it's suppose to be a bean if I'm not mistaken. You could grab the bean that was created by spring?

Comment: how?, this serializer is being called by spring after finishing the controller with @ResponseBody

Comment: don't you have an [Application Context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) that you use getBean on it?

Comment: No. its spring MVC. and everything is annotated

Comment: Sorry it is me that misread your comment.

Comment: If Spring isn't managing this bean, then it can't inject anything into it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Solution is **[SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)** if you are using Spring Framework 2.5+.

```
public class DesignSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Design> {

    @Autowired
        IDesignService designService;
    }

    public DesignSerializer(){
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);    
    }

...

}
```

I Hope that help you

Comment: Awesome. So simple compared to other suggestions all over the Web.

Comment: +1 for SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); It solve my problem too.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use the autowire in my case with jackson? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436279/autowire-in-deserialization-class

Comment: Does it work if you use a specific bean with @Qualifier?

Comment: @JosselinePerdomo Yes, it does

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working in junit tests?

Comment: It does when the test runs with  `SpringRunner`

Answer (score 23):

We had the same problem with JsonSerializer and Spring autowiring. The solution that worked for us was to make two constructors. One for Spring which sets the dependency as a static field, and another one that is used by the Jackson initialisation.

This works because the Spring dependency injection (autowiring) happens before Jackson initialises the serializer.

```
@Component
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    private static IDesignService designService;

    // Required by Jackson annotation to instantiate the serializer
    public MyCustomSerializer() { }

    @Autowired
    public MyCustomSerializer(IDesignService designService) {
        this.designService = designService;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String m, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider s) {
        gen.writeObject(MyCustomSerializer.designService.method(..));
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow I dont like the solution but I don't know how to do it on a better way. So I follow this way :-)

Answer (score 4):

I Solved the problem by creating a static field in a different bean and then `@Autowire` its setter method.

```
@Service("ToolBox")
@Transactional
public class ToolBox 
{
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ToolBox.class);


private static IService service;


@Autowired
public void setService(IService service)
{
    ToolBox.service = service;
}

public static IService getService()
{
    return ToolBox.service;
}}
```

like shown in this thread: [Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/autowired-static-field-spring-2-5)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot, [`@JsonComponent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html) will do the autowiring for you.

```
@JsonComponent
public class DesignSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Design> {
    @Autowired
    private DesignService designService;
}
```

Testing this serializer can then be done while autoconfiguring json support.

```
@AutoConfigureJson
@SpringBootTest
class DesignSerializerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    @Test
    void testDesignSerializer() {
        objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(new Design());
    }
}
```