# Autowire in deserialization class

Tags: java, spring, jackson, autowired

How to autowire inside deserialization class?

Here is the mapping class:

```
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy.class)
public class Container {


    @Autowired
    private CalcResourceUsage calcResourcePercentage;
    private ContainerStats containerStats;
    @Autowired
    private AverageResourceUsage averageResourceUsage;

    public Container(){
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }


    private String Id;


    private List<String> Names;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return Names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        Names = names;
    }

    public CalcResourceUsage getCalcResourcePercentage() {
        return calcResourcePercentage;
    }


    public AverageResourceUsage getAverageResourceUsage() {
        return averageResourceUsage;
    }

    public ContainerStats getContainerStats() {
        return containerStats;
    }

    public void setContainerStats(ContainerStats containerStats) {
        this.containerStats = containerStats;
    }
}
```

So I use jackson to map objects into this class, using this line of code:

```
Container[] containers = syncRestTemplate.getForObject(address + "json", Container[].class);
```

Then I have an array where for each container I need to do some calculations and if I can autowire `CalcResourceUsage` and `AverageResourceUsage`, I can do some calculations for each container.

currently `getAverageResourceUsage()` and `getCalcResourcePercentage()` return `null`

Comment: The best solution would be to instantiate your object from your JSON and then set the bean manually ! So you can autowire your beans inside the class that does the deserialisation job

Comment: But I cannot modify json, since it is coming from server

Comment: You mean the `Container`class ? So one solution would be to do : `List<Container> containers = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);`and then loop over the containers and set the `CalcResourceUsage`or `AverageResourceUsage`(by the way it seems that you could use an interface here to have a single abstraction)

Comment: if I loop over then I should use `new` but I don't want to use `new, isnt it?

Comment: interface for container class?

Comment: Don't forget create a factory bean for gson to get the baked bean from the context.

Comment: @RomanC I have done that

Comment: @secret If you done that then you can autowire

Comment: @RomanC I updated the text, do you mean that kind of bean ?

Comment: @secret gson is not a factory bean.

Comment: @RomanC if you show me how to convert gson bean to factory bean I would appreciate it. Because I am trying to do that and don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @secret To do it properly is a bit too broad, why do you use gson? is it a requirement or you can do it properly with Jackson?

Comment: @RomanC As long as it works, it does not matter, Gson or Jackson

Comment: Marking bean with `@Component` you made this bean as singleton, but you would need prototype, anyway it is useless, because instances are being created by message converter. There is a couple solution how to solve you issue. Create wrapper class and extract autowired properties and create transformer which will wrapp you DTOs or the another is make it static and using `@PostConstruct` initialize it. You would not need it initialize for every new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the deserialized objects to `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` for wiring (use `autowireBean()` method).

Example:

```
@Autowired
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

public void doDeserialization() {

   Container[] containers = // get them via jackson
   for (Container container : containers) {
      beanFactory.autowireBean(container);
      // container will now have its dependencies autowired.
   }
}
```