# Deserializing from JSON using foreign key

Tags: java, json, jpa, serialization, jackson

I have a many to one relationship: **A *<-->1 B** and I want to deserialize **A** from a JSON having **B**'s primary key (**B** exists in db with that primary key):

```json
{
    "b": 1
}
```

I have tried the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private B b;
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
    private List<A> a = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

but object **A** is created with `b = null`. How can I deserialize **A** with **b** property correctly instantiated from db?

Note: I am using Jackson version 2.6.1.

Comment: where do you want to get the b info from? look in db and create custom object or just create empty been with id field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options and here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46603075/1032167) :

1. `@JsonCreator` factory in `B` class ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618366/1032167))
2. Custom deserializer
3. Custom `ObjectIdResolver` for `@JsonIdentityInfo` like

   ```
   private class MyObjectIdResolver implements ObjectIdResolver {
       private Map<ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey,Object> _items  = new HashMap<>();

       @Override
       public void bindItem(ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey id, Object pojo) {
           if (!_items.containsKey(id)) _items.put(id, pojo); 
       }

       @Override
       public Object resolveId(ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey id) {
           Object object = _items.get(id);
           return object == null ? getById(id) : object;
       }

       protected Object getById(ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey id){
           Object object = null;
           try {
               //can resolve object from db here
               //objectRepository.getById((Integer)idKey.key, idKey.scope)
               object = id.scope.getConstructor().newInstance();
               id.scope.getMethod("setId", int.class).invoke(object, id.key);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return object;
       }

       @Override
       public ObjectIdResolver newForDeserialization(Object context) {
           return new MyObjectIdResolver();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean canUseFor(ObjectIdResolver resolverType) {
           return resolverType.getClass() == getClass();
       }
   }
   ```

   And use it like this:

   ```
   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
           resolver = MyObjectIdResolver.class, 
           property = "id", scope = B.class)
   public class B  {
      // ...
   }
   ```

Here is your case related [gist demo](https://gist.github.com/varren/c84da2f357a1d86b24bf137f3144cc3a) more broad [github project](https://github.com/varren/JsonIdentityInfoAlwaysAsObjectSerializationJackson) with some serialization thoughts

Comment: Hi @varren, thanks for your very interesting answer. I have one question about it: how can I pass an object repository to the `ObjectIdResolver`?

Comment: There are lots of options to consider. 1) Inject it in ObjectIdResolver on ObjectMapper creation and not in annotation [like this](https://gist.github.com/ftagsold/38a92cba5467fe74ae6b) 2) use some static reference to your repository/service/some repository factory 3) probably just autowire it [like here](https://github.com/terrestris/shogun2/blob/master/src/shogun2-core/src/main/java/de/terrestris/shogun2/converter/PersistentObjectIdResolver.java#L35-L41) more info  [here](https://github.com/terrestris/shogun2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PersistentObjectIdResolver&type=)

Comment: @y.luis ppl say you can use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`  similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21562939/1032167 I actually never had much lack with it.  Can probably try something like https://gist.github.com/varren/c84da2f357a1d86b24bf137f3144cc3a#file-myobjectidresolverautowired-java