# How to avoid retrieving a Spring managed bean from the context

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, apache-camel, inversion-of-control

My application receives messages, extracts data and persists the extracted data to a database.  Data is received via a Apache Camel channel, added to a FIFO.  The following code takes the next message from the FIFO and processes it.  However, in order to do this it needs to get a bean from the Spring application context:

```
private static void dispatch(Message msg) {
                if (msg == null) {
                    return;
                }
                // TODO: This really violates IoC.
                DomainObjectFactory factory = (DomainObjectFactory) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("domainObjectFactoryBean", DomainObjectFactory.class);

            // do something with message
```

This is the service class:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationContextProvider.class);

    private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return getCtx();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        log.debug("Loading context");
        ApplicationContextProvider.setCtx(ctx);
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public static void setCtx(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        ApplicationContextProvider.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

reading a message from the FIFO:

```
    void process(Object obj) {
        Message msg = (Message) obj;
        try {
            Dispatcher.process(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is really weak code, but I can't work out how to avoid it?  That is how to use Spring IoC to link the removal of a message from the FIFO to the message processing without having to retrieve the bean from the context.

Any advice / guidance appreciated

Comment: Inject the bean into your camel rout builder or processor or whatever. Stop using static methods for everything.

Comment: ok - I am fairly new to Ioc.  1) what is wrong with static methods? (I am trying to learn here) & 2) I am not exactly sure how to inject the bean.  I have added the code that reads from the FIFO (which runs in a different thread from the Camel code that writes to the FIFO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, your code would look a whole lot nicer, if you would use annotation or xml-based injection. This would be easier, if your `dispatch` method was not static. Still, you can inject Spring beans into static fields utilizing a `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`. Look here for more information:

[How can I inject local variables of a static method inside an abstract class using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629930/how-can-i-inject-local-variables-of-a-static-method-inside-an-abstract-class-usi/28632156#28632156)