# How to autowired a property in Junit class before executing any test with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to execute a code (in which I am auto wring a property) before executing any junit test using Before Class annotation but here problem is that annotated method called before application context load due to this I get the null value in property (helloWorld).

Please refer code for the same

```html
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/SpringBeans.xml")
public class JunitTest {

    @Autowired
    private static HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void methodBefore(){
        helloWorld.printHello();
        System.out.println("Before Class");
    }


    @Test
    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("In method 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("In method 2");
    }

    @Test
    public void method3(){
        System.out.println("In method 3");
    }

    @Test
    public void method4(){
        System.out.println("In method 4");
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void methodAfter(){
        System.out.println("After Class");
    }

}
```

In the same way I want to execute some code after executing all junit test.

please suggest how can I achieve above things

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use static on autowired field. see more here: [Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/autowired-static-field-spring-2-5)
remove the static from HelloWorld and you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autowire the static field - just remove the static modifier from `helloWorld` field.

Now the problem is that `@BeforeClass` annotation can be put on static methods only. You'll have to replace this method with Spring [TestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass(TestContext)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html#beforeTestClass-org.springframework.test.context.TestContext-) method

Depending on your requirements you might take on of the existing listeners like TransactionalTestExecutionListener which can call your methods say before the transaction is started, e.t.c.