# SessionFactory bean Initialised in Junit test but not in @SprinBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application which has hibernate integrated to it. I have wired in hibernate properties using Spring. When I use the `sessionFactory` in a Junit test I can do all the CRUD Operations but when I run the SpringBootApplication i.e., when I run the Main class which has `@SpringBootApplication` in it; it ends up getting an

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
 exception.

Any idea on how to solve this?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class GreetingRepositoryDAOTest {

    @Resource
    private BaseRepository greetingRepositoryImpl;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(((Greeting) greetingRepositoryImpl.findOne(1L)).getText());
        Greeting gr = new Greeting();
        gr.setText("Third Text");
        greetingRepositoryImpl.save(gr);
    }
}

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

applicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <import resource="hibernateContext.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.deepaksp.springboot" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
</beans>
```

[hibernateContext](https://github.com/spdeepak/Practice/blob/master/springboot/src/main/resources/hibernateContext.xml)

DAO Class

```
@Repository
public class BaseDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Criteria createCriteria(Class<?> clazz, String alias) {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(clazz, alias);
    }

    public Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your code? Are you trying to access bean in static context?

Comment: Give us the code of applicationContext.xml...

Comment: @staszek I am running the static main method which will use sessionFactory to create entities in database.

Comment: For using beans in static context you can use solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/autowired-static-field-spring-2-5

Comment: @staszek But I am not using beans in static context. I am just running the springboot application through a static main method which loads data to the DB and it doesn't use beans in static context anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot by default does not load beans `applicationContext.xml`. You can do it by annotating your `Application` class additionally with:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

This will add `BaseDAO` to Spring Boot application context, but it looks that you have more problems in your code:

- there is no need for creating `PropertyPlaceholder` for `application.properties` - it's being loaded by Spring Boot by default
- have a look at Spring Data JPA and how does it work with Spring Boot - it may simplify your Hibernate configuration (I see you have another `hibernateContext.xml` that most likely is not needed).
- consider dropping xml beans configuration in favour of `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: Thank you it worked with the @ImportResource. I will look into Spring Data JPA as well. I will need the propertyPlaceholder for application.properties for Junit tests, they won't work with out that.

Comment: If you use Spring Boot 1.4 instead of `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })`use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest` and `application.properties` will be loaded automagically.