# Can I write a Kotlin extension function that uses an autowired Spring bean?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to create an extension function whose implementation uses a Spring bean.  It didn't seem possible to do this by defining the extension function at the top level of a package.  I tried this:

```
@Component
class Converter {

    companion object {
        @Autowired
        lateinit var transformer: Transformer

        fun Class1.convert(): Class2 {
            return Class2 (this, transformer.transform(someStringProperty))
        }
    }    
}
```

where `transform` is a function that transforms some string to another string, and `Class1` is some class that has a `someStringProperty` property.  My hope was that other classes could `import pkg.Converter.Companion.convert` and then be able to use `x.convert()` where `x` is an object of type `Class1`.

The syntax works, and using `x.convert()` in other classes compiles fine.  But it results in an exception at run time: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property transformer has not been initialized`

It looks like Spring isn't autowiring the variable because it's in a companion object and not an actual component object.

Annotating the companion object with `@Component` didn't work.

I don't think moving `Class1.convert` directly inside `Converter` would work, because then using `x.convert()` would need an instance of the `Converter` object, and I don't see how to do this with the extension function syntax.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or do I have to give up on the extension function syntax?

Comment: Extensions are static functions, and anything in the companion object also results in `static` in bytecode. I believe Spring will only work with classes.

Answer (score 12):

The extension function can use the file scope private variable and in the
component's @PostConstruct method, assign "this" to the private variable.
This design adds a dependency from component to the extension function,
now they are both binding to the same private variable. But if they both are in the same problem, I think it is tolerable and there seems no other better way.

```
@Component
public class ClassOne {
    var value = Random.nextInt()

    @PostConstruct
    private fun init() {
        c1 = this
    }
}

private lateinit var c1 : ClassOne
fun String.appendC1() : String {
    return this + c1.value
}
```

And its test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [ClassOne::class])
class DependencyInjectionTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var autowiredConfiguration : ClassOne

    @Test
    fun testAccessComponentInExtension() {
        Assert.assertEquals(autowiredConfiguration.value, c1.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done because, because there's no way of auto-wiring static fields in Spring, as explained here: [Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields)

There are certain workarounds but the general recommendation is **don't do it.**

Having said that if you are really committed to make this solution work you might get aways with it by using a *Singleton with parameters* as shown in this blog post: https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e. Although frankly I think such a convoluted solution would completely defeat the purpose

Comment: But properties of the companion are _not_ static fields! We get a nested static class `Companion` with instance member `transformer`, a single instance of which is used as `Converter.Companion`.