# Spring Boot JPA not working

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have a controller class which is below. I have a `TagRepository` interface which extends JPA repository which I am using to save `TagReader` instance to my DB and it works fine when I use it in my controller class. However, when I try to use `tagRepository` in another class and try to save my `TagReader` object from there it throws a *null pointer* exception.

The following logic works fine.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
TagRepository tagRepository;

@Autowired
Rfid6204Connection rfid6204Connection;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public void testRepoController(){

    String tagid = "0x3504ACE6E0040E5147D516A6";
    String serial ="00333478";
    String departure ="2017-12-22T12:16:58.857";
    String type = "ISOC";


    TagReader tagReader = new TagReader(tagid,serial,departure,type,"5");


    tagRepository.save(tagReader);
  }
}
```

The following logic throws a null pointer exception.

```
@component
public class Rfid6204Connection{

    @Autowired
    static TagRepository tagRepository;

    public static void test(TagReader tag){
        tagRepository.save(tag);
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `Rfid6204Connection.test` as a static method. Spring doesn't work with Static methods. It works with Objects instantiated by the Spring Container. So change your `Rfid6204Connection` as below;

```
@Component
public class Rfid6204Connection{

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    public void test(TagReader tag){
        tagRepository.save(tag);
    }

}
```

And use it wherever you want as below;

```
@Autowired 
Rfid6204Connection rfid6204Connection;

// Within a method or constructor
rfid6204Connection.test(tag);
```

Comment: btw @Autowired is discouraged. Inject via constructor or setter. You would have spotted your error immediately

Answer (score 1):

You made the *Autowired* field *static* and when the class loader loads the static values, the Spring context is not yet loaded and your object is not correctly initialized; remove the static keyword:

```
@Autowired
private TagRepository tagRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't autowired static variables directly

then, you have some options.
first, autowired instance of TagRepository and after dependency injection 
set a instance to static variable

```
@Component
public class Rfid6204Connection {
private static TagRepository sTagRepository;

@Autowired
private TagRepository tagRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Rfid6204Connection.sTagRepository = tagRepository;
}
}
```

second prepare setter method of TagRepository and put a autowired

```
public class Rfid6204Connection {

    private static TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setTagRepository(TagRepository tagRepository) {
        Rfid6204Connection.tagRepository = tagRepository;
    }

}
```

but originally ... you shoudn't autowire to static variables.