# Autowired NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

```
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
   @Autowired
    private static XsenseServicesImpl xsense;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
      log.debug("-- Application Started --");
      xsense.getFullAnswers("Ciao", "it", "84b4d0897df757df594cbc68",null,false, null);
   }
 }
```

Why give me this error ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException App.main(App.java:39)

Because i did set @Autowired on static field?

Comment: about Autowire into static fields 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields

Comment: the answer is yes