# Autowired returns null in Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have following implementation which uses RestTemplate to make request to external service:

```
@Component
public class ExternalProvider {

    private ProviderProperties providerProperties;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("exprd")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("exprd")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    public ExternalProvider(ProviderProperties providerProperties) {
        this.providerProperties = providerProperties;
    }

    public String request(String requestParams) {
        ...
        return restTemplate.getForObject(providerProperties.getUrl(), String.class);
    }

}
```

And here is the test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ExternalProviderTest.TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExternalProviderTest {

    private ExternalProvider externalProvider;
    private ProviderProperties providerProperties;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("exprd")
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        providerProperties = new ProviderProperties();
        externalProvider = new ExternalProvider(providerProperties);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_makeRequest() {
        assertNotNull(externalProvider.request("params"));
    }
}
```

My test above is not running because of a **NullPointerException** when **restTemplate** is null. It seems that the **TestConfig** I define in my test is ignored. Anyone has an idea what did I configure wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756411/spring-autowired-resttemplate-is-null)

Comment: check this working solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591567/5108695

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Spring injection in your test, don't use new (or don't use Spring at all!)
 You also have to choose between constructor injection and autowired fields, avoid mixing it.

In your example I just removed the @before/new, and added @Autowired for Spring injection.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ExternalProviderTest.TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ExternalProviderTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExternalProvider externalProvider;
    @Autowired
    private ProviderProperties providerProperties;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("exprd")
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        @Bean
        public ExternalProvider  externalProvider () {
            return new ExternalProvider (providerProperties());
        }

        @Bean
        public ProviderProperties  providerProperties() {
            return new ProviderProperties();
        }



    }

    @Test
    public void test_makeRequest() {
        assertNotNull(externalProvider.request("params"));
    }
}
```

edit:
also it seems that your Bean weren't configured, Id did it here in the test, make me know if there are other configuration errors.