# Fail to wire two objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm trying to wire 2 objects using spring boot annotations but all my attempts in vain.

So I have a DataSource and I would like to use it in DAO class.
There is my code below.
Thank you!

```
            @Component
            public class DataBaseUtility {
                private static BasicDataSource dataSource;

                public DataBaseUtility() {
                    this.dataSource = getDataSource();
                }
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "";
                }

                public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {

                    if (dataSource == null)
                    {
                        dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
                    }
                    return dataSource;
                }
            }




            @Component
            public class JdbcPersonDao implements PersonDAO {
                @Autowired
                @Qualifier("dbu")
                private static DataBaseUtility dataBaseUtility;
                public JdbcPersonDao(){
                }

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
                    SpringApplication.run(RocApplication.class, 
                                                               args);
                    JdbcPersonDao jdbcPersonDao = 
                    context.getBean(JdbcPersonDao.class);
                    Person p = jdbcPersonDao.findByID(5L);
           }
```

Comment: Hello, could you how as the main class? or where you have created your component scan.

Comment: Inside JdbcPersonDao class there is a method that fetches data from database.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
                public class RocApplication {
                
                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(RocApplication.class, args);
                        JdbcPersonDao jdbcPersonDao = context.getBean(JdbcPersonDao.class);
                        Person p = jdbcPersonDao.findByID(5L);
                        System.out.println(p.toString());
                    }
                
                }

Comment: You cannot autowire static fields. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!