# Autowired TestEntityManager Has Null Pointer on TestEntityManager Object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to test a Spring Boot application using Spring Data REST and Spring Data JPA.  However the TestEntityManager object in the test file doesn't get autowired and thus is null.  I googled online and didn't find out what I have done wrong in the unit test file.  Can someone please help?

Entity -- Student:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Integer id; 

    .....// other fields
   }
```

And the Student repository:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student , Integer>{
  Student findById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

And I have a SpringApplication main file, but no controller.

And here is my test file.  I also tried with @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureTestEntityManager, but the entityManager is still null.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class StudentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private static TestEntityManager entityManager;  // entityManager is always Null 

    @Autowired
    private static StudentRepository repository; 

    private static Student student;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {

        entityManager.persistAndFlush(new Student("1"));  
          // Null Pointer exception because entityManager is null.
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {        
        assertNotNull(repository.findById());       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use @Autowired on static fields.
Refactor your test to use instance fields instead.
Remember that:

- Junit creates a fresh instance of test class before each test
- By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

[Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields)