# Why is hibernate failing to save?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I'm using Flyway to attempt to create and then seed a database when the Spring Boot web app starts up.  Flyway successfully creates the database tables in the first migration, but fails to populate them in the 2nd because of a NullPointerException.

Here is the migration code, called V2_seed_database.java, located in package db.migration:

```
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context;

import net.tekknow.medaverter.db.seeds.AppointmentSeeder;

public class V2__seed_database extends BaseJavaMigration {
    public void migrate(Context context) {
        AppointmentSeeder appointmentSeeder = new AppointmentSeeder();
        appointmentSeeder.seed();
    }
}
```

Here is the AppointmentSeeder code:

```
package net.tekknow.medaverter.db.seeds;

import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.tekknow.medaverter.domain.Appointment;
import net.tekknow.medaverter.service.AppointmentService;

@Service
public class AppointmentSeeder {
    @Autowired
    AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void seed() {
        String json = "[" +
            "{\"id\":1,\"patient_id\":1,\"dateTime\":\"10/29/2010\",\"physician_id\":1,\"lab_id\":1,\"note_id\":0}" +
        "]";
        org.json.JSONArray appointments = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i=0; i<appointments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject appointment = appointments.getJSONObject(i);
            Appointment dbAppointment = new Appointment();
            dbAppointment.setId(appointment.getInt("id"));
            dbAppointment.setPatientId(appointment.getInt("patient_id"));
            dbAppointment.setDateTime(appointment.getString("dateTime"));
            dbAppointment.setPhysicianId(appointment.getInt("physician_id"));
            dbAppointment.setLabId(appointment.getInt("lab_id"));
            dbAppointment.setNoteId(appointment.getInt("note_id"));
            appointmentService.save(dbAppointment);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AppointmentRepository code:

```
package net.tekknow.medaverter.db;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import net.tekknow.medaverter.domain.Appointment;

public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment,Integer> {
}
```

And here is the AppointmentService code:

```
package net.tekknow.medaverter.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import net.tekknow.medaverter.db.AppointmentRepository;
import net.tekknow.medaverter.domain.Appointment;

@Service
@Transactional
public class AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    AppointmentRepository repo;

    public void save(Appointment appointment) {
        System.out.println("AppointmentService.save: appointment="+appointment.toString());
        repo.save(appointment);  //its failing here
    }  
}
```

Here is the Appointment bean:

```
package net.tekknow.medaverter.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    private int patient_id;
    @Size(max = 32)
    private String date_time;
    private int physician_id;
    private int lab_id;
    private int note_id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
... other getters and setters, truncated for brevity
```

When I run the program, the migration starts but fails on this line:

```
    repo.save(appointment);  //its failing here
```

with the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
>   net.tekknow.medaverter.service.AppointmentService.save(AppointmentService.java:32)
>   ~[classes/:na]

Just before the line of code that fails, I output the contents of the object that it says is null, and its not null:

> AppointmentService.save: appointment=id:1, patient_id:1,
>   date_time:10/29/2010, physician_id:1, lab_id:1, note_id:0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not hibernate related, you are using spring dependency injection in an incorrect way: you are trying to autowire static fields, which is not allowed.

See [Can you use @Autowired with static fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/can-you-use-autowired-with-static-fields).

**Update**

Now you have

```
AppointmentService appointmentService = new AppointmentService();
```

instead of injecting this field to the Seeder.

Seeder needs to be a Spring-managed bean (`@Service` probably) if you want dependency injection to work. See also `@PostConstruct`, you may use it to call a method after a bean has been initialized.

**Update 2**

You are still instantiating Spring beans yourself with `new`, and thus not getting your dependencies injected.

```
AppointmentSeeder appointmentSeeder = new AppointmentSeeder();
```

You have however successfully pushed the problem one step towards Flyway. Now the problem is that Flyway migrations are not Spring beans: they are created by Flyway, not Spring, and thus don’t have their dependencies autowired by Spring.

Flyway 4.1 solved this problem by allowing to use a pre-existing Spring beans (or other Java objects) with a bit of config

See [API: Make it possible to use pre-instantiated Java-based migrations #1062](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1062).

> ```
> ApplicationContext applicationContext = ...; // obtain a reference to Spring's ApplicationContext.
>
> Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
>     .dataSource(url, user, password)
>     // Add all Spring-instantiated JavaMigration beans
>     .javaMigrations(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(JavaMigration.class).values().toArray(new JavaMigration[0]))
>     .load();
> flyway.migrate();
> ```

see also [JavaMigration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/JavaMigration) and [BaseJavaMigration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/BaseJavaMigration.html) javadoc.

Comment: I didn't have it that way initially.  Eclipse offered it as a "quick fix" to the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field repo".  So what should I do intead?

Comment: You probably only had the `repo` field as instance field, but the  `save` method was static. It is impossible to reach to instance fields from static methods (hence thequickfix). You need to make both field and method non-static

Comment: but the save method is one that gets inherited from public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment,Integer> {
} JpaRepository is Spring Boot (or Hibernate?) code, not mine.

Comment: Ah, yes of course.  Sorry I missed that.  Thank you.  I took it away and now the next error shows "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController' defined in file [C:\Users\Greg\Projects\MedAverter\target\classes\net\tekknow\medaverter\controller\AppController.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [net.tekknow.medaverter.controller.AppController] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/tekknow/medaverter/service/AppointmentService;"

Comment: I guess you solved this problem so will give you the credit.  Thank you!

Comment: Pls check if the service is discovered. Are you relying on default spring boot app layout (Application in root package) or are you customising it?

Comment: I'm relying on the default.  Here is how the app starts up, from MedAverter.java located in src>main>java>net>tekknow>medaverter folder.  @SpringBootApplication
public class MedAverter {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MedAverter.class, args);
 }

}

Comment: Unfortunately, despite the adjustments you suggested, I'm back to the original problem, so I unchecked the answer.  I updated the original post to include the change s you suggested.

Comment: Annotate the Seeder with `@Service`, add an autowired AppointmentService field (preferably use constructor injection), annotate `seed` with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: I added your suggestions to the main post code and my code, but alas, same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211746/discussion-between-lesiak-and-user3217883).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change the value of ** note_id** in your JSON file to **1** !

Comment: I changed it to 1 but made no difference

Answer (score 0):

do this in the AppointmentSeeder,

```
@Autowire
AppointmentService service;

public void seed() {
        String json = "[" +
            "{\"id\":1,\"patient_id\":1,\"dateTime\":\"10/29/2010\",\"physician_id\":1,\"lab_id\":1,\"note_id\":0}" +
        "]";
        org.json.JSONArray appointments = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i=0; i<appointments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject appointment = appointments.getJSONObject(i);
            Appointment dbAppointment = new Appointment();
            dbAppointment.setId(appointment.getInt("id"));
            dbAppointment.setPatientId(appointment.getInt("patient_id"));
            dbAppointment.setDateTime(appointment.getString("dateTime"));
            dbAppointment.setPhysicianId(appointment.getInt("physician_id"));
            dbAppointment.setLabId(appointment.getInt("lab_id"));
            dbAppointment.setNoteId(appointment.getInt("note_id"));
            service.save(dbAppointment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its @Autowired.  But that didn't work either.  Still getting the same error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at net.tekknow.medaverter.service.AppointmentService.save(AppointmentService.java:32) ~[classes/:na]"

Comment: I modified the code shown in the main post with your suggestions.