# NullPointerException & Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' from Hibernate Configuration class (using spring data jpa)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I have updated some dependency in my project after that my hibernate configuration class showing Nullpointerexception.

I'm using spring data JPA repository with hibernate, it's been more than 24 hours still not found any appropriate solution regarding small problem.

> Some Solution which I have already tried:-
>
> 1. Providing a bean name with @bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
> 2. Providing a ref like @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.carportal.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef
>      ="entityManagerFactory")
> 3. By changing dialect, By changing DriverClassName, by changing datasource manager

**Issue That I'm Facing**

```
19:29:11.756 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig.additionalProperties(HibernateConfig.java:74)
    at com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig.entityManagerFactory(HibernateConfig.java:46)
    at com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f78c3ea8.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f78c3ea8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9aea17b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f78c3ea8.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml file**

```
<properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <spring.version>5.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springdatajpa.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</springdatajpa.version>
        <spring.security.version>5.3.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <mysqlconnector.version>8.0.20</mysqlconnector.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.15.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator>6.1.5.Final</hibernate.validator>
</properties>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysqlconnector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springdatajpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**HibernateConfig Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:db.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.carportal.model", "com.carportal.repository", "com.carportal" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.carportal.repository")
public class HibernateConfig {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private static Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        logger.debug("Local Container Entity Manager Factory Bean");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.carportal");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carportadb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sam");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws NamingException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine"));

        /*
         * hibernateProperties.put(CONNECTION_PROVIDER,
         * env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class"));
         */

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

**db.properties**

```
# jdbc
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carportadb
jdbc.user=sam
jdbc.pass=root


# hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=InnoDBStorageEngine
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
#hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=InnoDBStorageEngine
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
```

Comment: Why are you configuring this manually instead of using Boot?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- ... I know with spring boot we don't have burdens of configuration-related stuff but I just wanted to practice many small things like entitymanagerfactory & sessionfactory, PlatformTransactionManager & JpaTransactionManager, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean & LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean and some different kind of connection pooling just making some error to get things more clear.

Comment: It's your choice, of course, but this "practice" is not likely to be useful to you. I haven't done that manual configuration since 2013; it's simply not needed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Stackstrace says that you have a NullPointerException in your method com.carportal.config.HibernateConfig.additionalProperties().

Here you try to use the autowired field "env".

As far as I know, you cannot autowire a static field (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019053/13454816). Try to remove the static on your field.

Comment: using static was a too bad mistake from my side, thanks for help me out.@omido can you please help me out with Hikari connection pooling configuration.

Comment: @ShambhuGohel I'm glab, that I could help you. 
I have not really experiences with the Hikari connection pool.