# how to stop HQL hibernate insert multiple data inserted?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

Implementation: HQL hibernate. Im trying to save 1 data but what happen is its saving `many data` the only i stop it is by `result > 1 to NullPointerException`. I already put some  `session.close()` still saving multiple.

Hibernate has `save` but where not gonna use that.

```
@Override
    public Product save(Product product) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
  
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            String hql = "INSERT INTO Product  ( productname, productbrand, productprice, productdescription, productquantity, productexpirationdate) " +
                "SELECT   productname, productbrand, productprice, productdescription, productquantity, productexpirationdate FROM Product ";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            Integer result =  query.executeUpdate();
        
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();

             if (result == 0 ||result == null  ) {
                   
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            
           // if (result > 1 || result >= 0 ||result == null  ) {
           //      
           ///  throw new NullPointerException();
            //}
            

        return product;
    }
```

Example in data in database insert 1 data then suddenly  inserting multiple data.
how to stop this?

```
'1', 'Hello1234', 'Hello', '2022-10-27 00:00:00', 'Hello1234', '1.4', '10', NULL
'2', 'Hello1234', 'Hello', '2022-10-27 00:00:00', 'Hello1234', '1.4', '10', NULL
'3', 'Hello1234', 'Hello', '2022-10-27 00:00:00', 'Hello1234', '1.4', '10', NULL
'4', 'Hello1234', 'Hello', '2022-10-27 00:00:00', 'Hello1234', '1.4', '10', NULL
```

Database query

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_product` (
  `purchase_item` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productbrand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `productdescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `productexpirationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `productprice` double NOT NULL,
  `productquantity` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`purchase_item`),
  UNIQUE KEY `purchase_item_UNIQUE` (`purchase_item`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Perhaps you want some unique constraints in your table?

Comment: @Kayaman I tried the ID as unique constraints but its still desame multiple saving

Comment: Yes but you also have it as auto increment.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, i also updated my post question with database query

Comment: is the table initially empty before you insert data? because in your query you inserting the existing data, or you can say that it will duplicate existing data

Comment: @hphp yes its empty. and yes i just notice just now it will duplicate existing data

Comment: So everything seems to be in order. You're inserting new rows and they're getting inserted. Since you don't have any unique columns besides the PK, you get duplicates. The primary key is autoincremented for each insert.

Comment: so by `suddenly inserting multiple data`, did you call the method multiple times and expect it is not inserting duplicate data? or did you call the method once, but the data inserted multiple times?

Comment: @hphp i call it 1 time then its saving multiple time and  duplicating other data.

Comment: idk, i don't see where you set your `product` to your query, but maybe for now can you try creating the query using `PreparedStatement` first? just to make sure it didn't duplicated because of your query

Comment: @hphp here for full detail this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561268/hql-orm-hibernate-implementation-error-null ]

Answer (score 0):

fix `getSessionFactory().openSession()` to
`getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`

reference link  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession#:~:text=openSession()%20always%20opens%20a,t%20need%20to%20close%20this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession#:%7E:text=openSession()%20always%20opens%20a,t%20need%20to%20close%20this).

Answer (score 0):

What's a weird query?

```sql
INSERT INTO Product ( productname, productbrand, productprice, productdescription, productquantity, productexpirationdate) 
SELECT  productname, productbrand, productprice, productdescription, productquantity, productexpirationdate 
FROM Product";
```

You select data from `Product` and insert it to the same `Product` table simultaneously.
That's why!